# can't get pcre to work in c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, pcre

I'm pretty new to c++, as in I'm still learning the basic of it

anw. I want to use pcre in it, but have so far been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

I'm running Ubuntu and have in my latest attempt tried to install the libpcre3-dev package (I should mention that I am rather new to Linux too)

I included pcre with

```
#include <pcrecpp.h>
```

currently I'm getting the error "undefined reference to pcrecpp::RE::no_arg" whenever I try to define an RE object

```
pcrecpp::RE reg("fys|smi|int|fok|arv|kar");
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and or give me a step by step guide on how to do it.

And I do know that c++ have a regex library, but since I'm used to pcre from php, that is what I'm going for

Comment: You're getting this error when you link? Are you linking with the PCRE library?

Comment: Is your library path(-L tag) set properly to point to the location where your .so files are located for the libpcre package??

Comment: I get the error when I compile, and I have no idea about the other things, which is why I ask

Comment: There are various possible duplicates of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294404/pcre-error-undefined-symbol-zn7pcrecpp2re6no-arge, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568644/compiling-error-c-undefined-references-using-pcre-library, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509834/how-can-i-link-my-c-code-with-the-pcre-library-linker-errors-currently-being-t, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655403/help-using-pcre-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `-lpcrecpp` on the command line to link your program with the PCRE library. Just including the declarations in a header file is not enough.

Comment: Like this? g++ test.cpp -lpcre -o test,
If so, its not working

Comment: Oops, sorry, you should use `-lpcrecpp` instead.

Comment: could you by any chance also explain why I can't use pcrecpp::RE_Options.set_utf8()

Comment: About that, please post a separate question with a detailed explanation of what you're trying and what happens.